# Error with: meteor add ethereum:web3

Tags: web3js, bug, meteor

If I run the command:

```
$> meteor add ethereum:web3
```

I get the following error message:

```
 => Errors while adding packages:             

While checking for ethereum:web3@0.18.4:
error: No compatible binary build found for this package. Contact the package author and ask them to publish it for your platform.
```

Does anybody have an idea what is going on here?

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Please let me know if you get the solution.

Comment: I had a similar error with a nodejs package last week, could you point us to the docs where you found that instructions to add `ethereum:web3`?

Comment: The instructions are probably these: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Dapp-using-Meteor#create-your-%C3%90app

Comment: I used the command: $ meteor add ethereum:tools . This obviously installed the ethereum:web3 but with the version 0.15.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In windows cmd: `meteor add ethereum:web3@=0.18.3`

Just add the previous version, worked for me.

Comment: Like @Miguel mentioned it workes loading previous version

Comment: That worked for me on a linux system as well

Answer (score 4):

Using $ meteor add ethereum:tools worked for me. As you may see below, it added web3. Thanks

3stack:bignumber               added, version 2.0.0
amplify                        added, version 1.0.0
ethereum:tools                 added, version 0.6.0
ethereum:web3                  added, version 0.15.3
frozeman:persistent-minimongo  added, version 0.1.8
frozeman:storage               added, version 0.1.9
localstorage                   added, version 1.0.12